# I want to build a virtual web server from python. Where do I start?

Tags: virtualization, web-server, python

I use Python, and I'm familiar with its capabilities and syntax. I want to create a web server that can receive and send JSON data packets. Sorry about the short question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Where should I start to do X?" questions are not well received here. You should do at least a bit of research of your own.

If *after starting* you have *specific technical questions*, you are welcome to ask. But this is not the place for tutorials. There are plenty around.